# Setting the mutability flag in PendingIntent on Android 12 when prompting phone number

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-12

In Android 12, it is required to [specify the mutability of the PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability). In the signing screen the HintRequest class is used and  **PendingIntent** is returned by the **getHintPickerIntent** method. The code is as follows,

```
 HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build();
 PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(activity).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);//crashes here on android 12
```

The error in logcat is this,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

My question is how to set the mutability flag in the pending intent once it is created.

Comment: There does not appear to be a `HintRequest` in the Android SDK. Is this from a library?

Comment: @CommonsWare Its in com.google.android.gms.auth library. reference - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/package-summary

Comment: Hmmmm... a `PendingIntent` is sealed once created. There is no public API for modifying its contents. Are you on the latest version of that library? Google needs to update the library to accommodate this new requirement.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right. Updating to the latest version fixed the issue. => com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0

Comment: Same problem facing! Did you get any solution?

Comment: @InsaneCat updating to the latest lib version was the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because of the auth library is not having the latest SDK version (31) requirements. I had a similar issue and it got fixed after updating the latest auth library in build Gradle.

Update your auth library version to 20.2.0 or later version

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0"
```